# iPad supported device orientations and landscape launch image

Tags: xcode, ipad, orientation, landscape

If neither (left or right) of the iPad landscape device orientations are supported, does the landscape launch image ever get shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently working on a portrait orientation only app. I have not found a way to launch the app with the landscape launch image shown. So, i don't think that the landscape image will ever been shown. Still you should include it in your app bundle to pass the App Store approval process.